# ODL Chlorine ping mininet hosts

Tags: ping, mininet, sdn, opendaylight

I am trying to use the SDN ODL Chlorine controller, but I do not have access to the mininet host. I installed the features [text](https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/openflowplugin/en/stable-chlorine/users/installation.html). However, ping does not work.

For the other version, it was very easy only to install the odl-l2switch-switch, but now I do not find a good feature. Which features should be used?

Thanks

ping the mininet host.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

sudo ovs-vsctl set-controller s1 tcp:127.0.0.1:6633

./bin/karaf clean

---

Only

---

feature:install odl-restconf odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest

install flows :

sudo ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 add-flow s1 actions=NORMAL

Tutorial https://learning.knetsolutions.in/docs/odl/